# DatatTable draw is not working after first time initialization

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTable and facing issue while filtering and sorting server side data. It works fine on page load for first time but next time when I tried to sort or filter the data it doesn't redraw the rows.

I have debug it and found it fetched the correct data but doesn't draw new data.

```
             var modifyRequestData = function (d) {

                var d = $.parseJSON(d);

                var jsonData = {};
                jsonData.data = d.Products;
                jsonData.recordsTotal = d.TotalCount;
                jsonData.recordsFiltered = d.Products.length

                return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            };

            var modifyParams = function (d) {

                var params = {};

                params.Draw = d.draw;
                params.Page = parseInt(d.start) + 1;
                params.OrderColumn = d.columns[d.order[0].column].data;
                params.OrderType = d.order[0].dir;

                $(settings.searchFormID).find("input, select").each(function () {

                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var name = this.name;

                    params[name] = val;
                });

                return params;
            };

            var getProducts = function () {

                var columns = [
                  { "data": "Id" },
                  { "data": "Name" },
                  { "data": "Price" },
                  { "data": "Id" }
                ]

                var modifiedColumns = [{
                    'targets': 0,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'width': '1%',
                    'className': 'dt-body-center',
                    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox">';
                    }
                }, {
                    'targets': columns.length - 1,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'width': '1%',
                    'className': 'dt-body-center',
                    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return ''
                    }
                }];

                var ajaxConfig = {
                    "url": "/api/products/",
                    "dataFilter": modifyRequestData,
                    "data": modifyParams
                }

                productDatatable = $('#listContainer table').DataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "lengthChange": true,
                    "ajax": ajaxConfig,
                    "columns": columns,
                    'columnDefs': modifiedColumns
                });

                productDatatable.on('draw.dt', function () {
                    alert('Table redraw');
                });

            };
```

Comment: Well, your 'orderable' and 'searchable' parameters are false for all column definitions. That might be the problem. Do you have a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem as you and I finally discover that I had hardcoded for test reason the draw value to 1 in the return object of the server side.

So since the value of the draw property on the first call was 1 the datatable was update with my result, but on the update the draw value was 4 and I was still returning 1.

Yon can find in the **jquery.dataTables.js** file this function :

```
function _fnAjaxUpdateDraw ( settings, json )
```

And especially this code :

```
    if ( draw ) {
        // Protect against out of sequence returns
        if ( draw*1 < settings.iDraw ) {
            return;
        }
        settings.iDraw = draw * 1;
    }
```

After setting correctly the value of the draw property on the server side, everything started to work well.